# How to format current datetime in this format "2020-04-10T13:58:59.000+0000" in TypeScipt

Tags: java, angular, typescript, datetime, format

Sorry for the silly question, but any help is greatly appreciated!

**I need help getting the current datetime in *TypeScipt* in a particular format "2020-04-10T13:58:59.000+0000".**

Let me give some context to the problem. I have an Angular 9 frontend with a Spring Boot backend along with an Oracle 11g DB. It's a simple CRUD frontend.

In java, the POJO Entity has this parameter in regards to the DateTime

```
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "datetime")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date datetime;
```

So the task is to pass the a string datetime from angular in this format "2020-04-10T13:58:59.000+0000" to the Spring API

Once again, sorry if this question has been asked before or is trivial.

**SOLUTION**

Thank you for responses! For anyone with the same problem, here's the solution

```
import {formatDate} from "@angular/common";

let formatedDate = formatDate(new Date(),'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.SSSZZZ','en-US');
console.log(formatedDate);

>> 2020-04-25T11:24:46.821+0300
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your own solution. Allow me to suggest that you do it in an answer, not in an edit to the question. In an answer is where people will look for it first and be most likely to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

formatDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.SSS+ZZZ')

https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate